# Storyboard - Object inside an object as IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, storyboard, iboutlet

I was going through [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKH0xWjw2ps) good tutorial on **MVVM** pattern taking an example of a simple api call. Here is a final structure of `UIViewController` in **Storyboard**:

[image]

**VC:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewModel: ViewModel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**VM:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewModel: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var client: ApiClient!
}
```

**ApiClient:**

```
import UIKit

class ApiClient: NSObject {

}
```

**Observation :**

Throughout, I have learnt that *ViewModel* (considering MVVM), should never have `UIKit` reference. Although using **Storyboards** for MVVM proves to have different outcome. Since we are taking `IBOutlet` in a *ViewModel*.

**Query:**

Is it right to use **Storyboard** and object `IBOutlet` for **MVVM**?

Comment: I wonder how will you handle case where you need to create ViewModel instance by passing parameter to its init. Though I have seen this approach, I could not figure out the way to create initWithParameter approach to create ViewModel hence refrained from using it. I rather use dependency injection libraries or simply create a protocol of your own to create a provision to insert view model to viewController at runtime

Comment: @SandeepBhandari : To be very honest, storyboard approach is quite new to me. The way I see it, VM reference would be itself initialised when the view is loaded since it is IBOutlet. And very can always create custom init for that matter. But still not very clear on this.

Comment: @AhmadF : Point taken. However, if UIKit is introduced in VM, that would change everything. This would conflict with the basic principle of MVC or MVVM, i.e. Separation of Control.

Comment: Remember that you can control it, if importing the UIKit is required just for creating a IBOutlet property, it seems to be fine. However, *don't* let the view model to handle the "View" responsibilities, that's it :) If you are insisting on removing `import UIKit` from the view model, you could declare the client as: `var client: ApiClient!` without the need of doing the injection from the storyboard, you would need to it in the code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning that:

> I have learnt that ViewModel (considering MVVM), should never has
>   UIKit reference.

seems to be not always correct, it is not standard rule of thumb when creating the view model, therefore if importing the `UIKit` is required just for declaring a property as an `IBOutlet`, it would be not a bad idea.

I believe the purpose of mentioning that the view should never import the `UIKit` is because we want a *precise* view model, means that we don't want to break the principles of the MVVM pattern by letting the view model -unintentionally- taking care of the "View" layer responsibilities, by avoiding importing the `UIKit` in the view model, we could guarantee that such a conflict won't happen; There is no doubt that you -as a developer- would be able to recognize that conflict...

Nevertheless, you still able to remove the `import UIKit` from the view model, by declaring the `client` as:

```
var client: ApiClient!
```

without marking it as an `IBOutlet`, thus you would need to inject it programmatically instead of doing it via storyboard.

Comment: Appreciate your view. Taking variable instead of IBOutlet seems a bold move. But how about ViewModel. If we are doing this via Storyboard. In that case, though we may take variable of ViewModel in ViewController but that would defeat the purpose of *MVVM via Storyboard*

Comment: @Nitish *"that would defeat the purpose of MVVM via **Storyboard**"* exactly! that's why at this point importing the `UIKit` in the view model would be required. personally, I faced both cases and injecting the client via the storyboard was the preferable one... Also, [you could check this sample](https://github.com/yayitserica/MVVM-Blog) of how it could be done :)